# Start a ionic project in linux

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. I am trying to start a ionic project. I install cordova and when I'm going to add the android platform to the project using 'ionic platform android' it gives me this error.

```
an error occurred while listing android targets
```

I also set the path to android sdk and ant by adding following lines to my *.bashrc* file

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-bundle/sdk/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$HOME/android-bundle/sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"
export ANT_HOME="$HOME/ant"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"
```

But still I get the above error. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in you .bashrc file.

```
export ANT_HOME="/usr/bin/ant"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"
export HOME="/home/username"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-bundle/sdk/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$HOME/android-bundle/sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

I always explicitly define the paths globally.

Mine looks a little like this - from the terminal I type:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/dev/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/dev/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools
```

If this doesn't work, try updating the sdk

Answer (score 1):

type in your linux terminal:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/android-sdk-linux

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/android-sdk-linux/tools

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools